# Find row before first null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table similar to this

```
timestamp              val
2017-05-04 06:00:00      2
2017-05-04 08:00:00      3
2017-05-04 09:35:00      5
2017-05-04 10:05:00      
2017-05-04 11:15:00      8
2017-05-04 12:10:00      
2017-05-04 13:35:00     12
```

and I'd like to find the record before the first null in val field (the one with 09:35 timestamp in the example table).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks

EDIT: using postgres 9.5
EDIT2: sorry everybody I forgot to mention that sometimes there are no nulls, and in that case I need just the max timestamp. The answers provided so far don't work in that case (sorry again for the loose explanation in the original question)

Comment: What if first row (with lowest timestamp) have null value in `val`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [lead()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-window.html) function returns next value of a partition using an specific order.

If there is no null values, this solution returns last record.

> ```
> with lg as
> (
>     select tm, val, 
>            lead(val) over (order by tm) next_val
>     from   your_table
> )
> select   tm as "timestamp", val
> from     lg
> where    next_val is null
> order by tm
> limit 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> timestamp           | val
> :------------------ | --:
> 2017-05-04 09:35:00 |   5
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=13c0b541ed30e6f765f3135a75161c99)*

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . .

```
select t.*
from t
where t.timestamp < (select min(t2.timestamp) from t t2 where t2.val is null)
order by t.timestamp desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. I forgot to mention that sometimes there are no null values, and the query should return the last record in that case. I think this query will fail when there are no nulls. Am I right? Do you know how to accomodate for this case? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If not null value it will return the last row else above record of first null value.

```
select t.*
from t
where  t.timestamp <= (select min(t2.timestamp) 
                        from NAMEs t2 
                        where (t2.val is null or t2.timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from NAMES) ) 
                )
        and t2.val is not null        
order by t.timestamp desc
limit 1 ;
```